# Alternative to a Get request with a body: Post vs Put vs smth else

Tags: rest, http

I know there are many questions like "How to use GET request with body" and in each of them it is recommended to use the verb `POST` instead. However, I do not really want to use it, because as a rule, `POST` requests do not guarantee idempotency. Maybe it's better to use `PUT`, which should guarantee idempotency? Or maybe some other one from the list of safe verbs?

Comment: http requests won't guarantee idempotency on a server level, you can do whatever you want with the request depending on de server implementation. You didn't state your usecase but I think you are best of with just an ordenairy post request and handle the idempotency on the software design.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware that idempotency depends on my implementation. It's about how my clients will understand my methods. If this is a post request, the client may decide that it is not safe to retry it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Maybe it's better to use PUT, which should guarantee idempotency?

No.  The problem is that PUT has semantics beyond the promise of being handled idempotently.  Trying to hijack it as a query mechanism creates the opportunity for a mess, when general purpose components that understand HTTP assume that PUT means PUT.

POST has fewer constraints on its use.  [It is okay to use POST](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post).

> maybe some other one from the list of safe verbs?

There aren't many safe methods with request bodies, and you still have the potential problem of whether the implications of the method are too tightly constrained.

In late 2020, the [HTTP-WG adopted](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/ietf-http-wg/2020OctDec/0194.html) a proposal for "GET with a body"; so eventually we should see a new method, probably called SEARCH, with semantics that will be useful for safe queries.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But the POST semantics are also not suitable for the method of getting data without changing the state, aren't they?